# How to set django server starts when system is on

Tags: django, ubuntu

How to set django server starts when system is on in ubuntu? (how crontab  setting when system is on)

Comment: Do you mean you want to activate the development server when you log into your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: simple by using a bash file

Comment: yes,i want to activate development server in production

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you shouldn't.

The development server is not for use in production: that's why it's called the development server. If you install a proper web server like Apache or Nginx, it will already be configured to start when the system does.

(You wouldn't use cron for this anyway: you would do something with init.)

Comment: django server only for developement purpose?,can't use in production ?